# Custom field not showing on edit form

Tags: entities

I'm fairly new to drupal development and still trying to wrap my brain around the API.  I run an athletic based website and need to be able to store race times using a mm:ss.00 format.  I haven't seen any contributed modules that can do this, so I decided to create my own. I basically used an example field as my model and have gone through creating the field.  When I activated the code, I can add the field to the content type.  The field shows as an option when managing the display.  However, the field doesn't show up when I edit the content type.  I've gone through the code and compared it to others and I just can't figure out why.  Below is the code for my module. Any ideas?

```
    /**
     * Implementation of hook_field_info().
     */
     function racetime_field_info() {
        return array(
             'racetime' => array(
                 'label' => t('Time'),
                 'description' => t('Time in format mm:ss.00'),
                 'settings' => array(),
                 'instance_settings' => array('number_decimals'=>2),
                 'default_widget' => 'racetime_default_widget',
                 'default_formatter' => 'racetime_default_formatter'
             )
         );
     }


     /**
        * Implements hook_field_instance_settings_form()
        */
     function racetime_field_instance_settings_form($field,$instance) {
         return array(
             'number_decimals' => array(
                 '#type' => 'textfield',
                 '#size' => 4,
                 '#title' => t('Number of decimals'),
                 '#default_value' => $instance['settings']['number_decimals'],
                 '#description' => t('The number of decimal places to use'),
             )
         );
     }

     /**
        * Implements hook_field_widget_info()
        */
     function racetime_field_widget_info() {
            return array(
                 'racetime_default_widget' => array(
                        'label' => t('Time Field'),
                        'field types' => array('racetime')
                 ),
            );
     }

     /**
        * Implements hook_field_is_empty()
        */
     function racetime_field_is_empty($item,$field) {
            if($item['value'] === '') {
                    return TRUE; 
            }
            return FALSE;
     }

     /**
        * Implements hook_field_widget_form()
        */
     function racetime_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
            $value = isset($items[$delta]['value']) ? $items[$delta]['value'] : '';
            $numDecimals = $instance['settings']['number_decimals'];
            $widget = $element;
            $widget['#delta'] = $delta;

            $widget += array(
                 '#type' => 'textfield',
                 '#default_value' => $value,
                 '#size' => 8,
                 '#maxlength' => 15,
                 '#number_decimals' => $numDecimals,
                 '#value_callback' => '_racetime_widget_process_callback',
            );
            if (!isset($widget['description']) || !strlen($widget['description'])) {
                $widget['#description'] = t('Add description here');
            }
            if (!isset($widget['#process'])) {
                $widget['#process'] = array();
            }
            if (!in_array('_racetime_widget_process_callback', $widget['#process'])) {
                $widget['#process'][] = '_racetime_widget_process_callback';
            }

        $element['value'] = $widget;
        echo "<!-- \$element = " . print_r($element,true) . "-->\n";
        return $element;
     }


     /**
        * Implementation of hook_field_formatter_info
        */
     function racetime_field_formatter_info() {
            return array(
                 'racetime_default_formatter' => array(
                        'label' => t('Time'),
                        'field types' => array('racetime'),
                        'settings' => array(),
                        ),
                 );
     }

     /**
        *
        */
        function racetime_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode,$form, &$form_state) {
            $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
            $settings = $display['settings'];

            $element = array();

            if($display['type'] == 'racetime_default_formatter') {
                $element['number_decimals'] = array(
                    '#type' => 'textfield',
                    '#title' => t('Number of decimals'),
                    '#size' => 4,
                    '#description' => t('The number of decimals to use'),
                    '#default_value' => $settings['number_decimals'],
                    '#required' => TRUE,
                    );
            }
            return $element;
        }
     /**
        * Implements hook_help
        */
        function racetime_help($path, $arg) {
            switch ($path) {
                case "admin/help#racetime":
                    return '<p>' . t("A field for recording a race time in the format m:ss.00") . '</p>';
                    break;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Implements hook_field_formatter_view()
         */
        function racetime_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
            $element = array();

            if($display['type'] == 'racetime_default_formatter') {
                foreach($items as $delta => $item) {
                    $element[$delta]['#theme'] = 'racetime';
                    $element[$delta]['#value'] = $item['value'];
                    $element[$delta]['#number_decimals'] = $display['settings']['number_decimals'];
                }
            }

            return $element;
        }

        /**
         * Implements hook_theme()
         */
        function racetime_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
            return array(
                'racetime' => array(
                        'variables' => array('value' => '', 'number_decimals' => 2)
                )
            );
        }

        /**
         * Theme racetime
         */
         function theme_racetime($variables) {

             $classes = array();
                $html = '<span class="' . implode(' ',$classes) . '">';
                $html .= _racetime_integer_to_formatted($variables['value'],$variables['number_decimals']);
                $html .= '</span>';
                return $html;
         }
        /**
         * Function to convert a string to integer
         */
        function _racetime_string_to_int($str, $numDecimals = 2) {
            //valid formats could be 16:47.17 (minutes:seconds.hundredths)
            //or 1:53:45.35 (hours:minutes:seconds.hundredths)
            //$numDecimals is the number of decimal places to carry after the seconds

            //split the string by colons, first.
            $parts = explode(":", $str);

            $numParts = count($parts);
            $hours = 0;
            $minuts = 0;
            $seconds = 0;
            if($numParts == 3) {
                $hours = $parts[0];
                $minutes = $parts[1];
                $seconds = $parts[2];
            }
            elseif($numParts == 2) {
                $minutes = $parts[0];
                $seconds = $parts[1];
            }
            else {
                $seconds = $parts[0];
            }
            //convert hours and minutes to seconds
            $sec_hours = $hours * 3600;
            $sec_minutes = $minutes * 60;
            //add all together to get the total number of seconds
            $seconds = $sec_hours + $sec_minutes + $seconds;

            /**
             * now convert the seconds to an integer value
             * here we multiple seconds by 10 to the power of number of decimals.
             * if the user wants one decimal, we'd be expecting a value like
             * 1:54.3, in which case we'd have a seconds value of 114.3.  10^1 is 10,
             * and we'd be left with an integer of 1143.  For the default of two,
             * we would expect a value of 1:54.34, which would give us 114.34 * 10^2 or
             * 114.34 * 100 = 11434.
             */
            $seconds_int = $seconds * (10^$numDecimals);

            return $seconds;
        }
        /**
         * function to convert an integer value to a time
         */
        function _racetime_integer_to_formatted($seconds, $numDecimals=2) {
            //first convert the integer value to seconds
            $sec = $seconds / (10^$numDecimals);
            if($sec < 60) {
                return number_format($sec,$numDecimals);
            }
            else {
                $hours_str = '';
                //get number of minutes
                $minutes = floor($sec / 60);
                $seconds_str = $sec - ($minutes * 60);
                //if seconds is less then 10, then add a leading 0
                if($seconds_str < 10) { $seconds_str = 0 . number_format($seconds_str,$numDecimals); }
                //if the number of minutes is greater than 60, then convert
                //minutes to hours and minutes
                if($minutes > 60) {
                    $hours = floor($minutes / 60);
                    $minutes_str = $minutes - ($hours * 60);
                    if($minutes_str < 10) {
                        $minutes_str = 0 . $minutes_str;
                    }
                    $hours_str = $hours . ':';
                }
                else {
                        $minutes_str = $minutes;
                }
                $time_string = $hours_str . $minutes_str . ":" . $seconds_str;

                return $time_string;
            }
        }
        /**
         * Widget helper to present seconds as readable formatte string
         */
        function _racetime_widget_process_callback($element, $form_state) {
            if(!isset($element['#value'])) {
                $element['#value'] = '';
            }
            $element['#value'] = _racetime_integer_to_formatted($element['#value'],$element['#number_decimals']);
        }
```

**EDIT**
It appears to have something to do with this line

```
 if (!in_array('_racetime_widget_process_callback', $widget['#process'])) {
     $widget['#process'][] = '_racetime_widget_process_callback';
 }
```

as soon as I commented it out, the form appears, even though the data doesn't get saved correctly.

Comment: Would it be possible to leverage the Date module? Times are stored in unix timestamp which goes down to the second... but you probably need those milliseconds eh?

Comment: Yup, need those hundredths of a second. Competition is generally timed to the hundredths or thousandths of a second.

Comment: There was some discussion concerning this for the HMS field module in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1586200). Might want to consider a contribution to that one, although I have no idea about status of things.

Comment: HMS is actually what I based the above on.  For now, I'll use what I have. I fixed the issue by fixing a bug in the value_callback value.  I was using the process_call function by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in the `hook_field_widget_form()`

```
'#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta] : '',
```